# IIS subapplications of a main site have problems fetching static files accesssed programmatically by Web application root operator (~)

Tags: iis, rewrite

I have a Windows Server in a local LAN having different asp.net core applications written in blazor and Razor.

The Windows Server has a static IP 192.168.1.5.

I want to access the sites:

- main (192.168.1.5)
- app1 (192.168.1.15/app1)
- app2
- app3

I setup IIS with a site with a simple static html file.

I want to run the apps simply by 192.168.1.5/app1 (or app2, pr app3)

When I try to access app1 (a razor web app) with the above format, I can access the application, but all static files (css, images etc) that are placed inside wwwroot folder of app1 are using context `/` instead of `/app1`. (i.e. `192.168.1.5/images/p.png` instead of `192.168.1.5/app1/images/p.png`).
Any help?

Comment: That’s by design I think. ~/ isn’t the recommended way to specify resource paths and you need to use Server.MapPath to resolve it. This is more like a Stack Overflow old thread.

Comment: Old or new, I have searched hut I haven't any practical solution.